# how to convert tgs files to gif?

Tags: node.js, type-conversion, bots, telegram

How do I convert tgs gif files to nodejs? Is there any conversion library? I get this file from the telegram bot when I send a sticker

I get a download url like this => https://api.telegram.org/file/bot5147264578:AAEu_VyFh1Fe-k2R-B2SZEsoG2viSdQNuqE/stickers/file_56.tgs

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean covert `tgs` to Lottie `json`? You can just extract it with Gzip